# djangorestframework ModelSerializer serialize model Object but data is empty{}

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I use djangorestframework, when I serializer a list of model objects,serializer.data is work, but when I serializer the model object only,serializer.data is the empty{}, why?

model:

```
class WindowInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(WxAccount, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    add_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

ModelSerializer:

```
class WindowInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = WindowInfo
        fields = '__all__'enter code here
```

view:

```
class WindowInfoViewset(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.CreateModelMixin):
    serializer = WindowInfoSerializer
    queryset =WindowInfo.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = [CustomerAuthentication]

    def create(self, request: Request, *args, **kwargs):
        window_info_list = WindowInfo.objects.all()
        window_info = window_info_list[0]

        window_info_list = WindowInfoSerializer(data=window_info_list, many=True)
        window_info_list.is_valid()
        window_info = WindowInfoSerializer(data=window_info, many=False)
        window_info.is_valid()

        print("window_info_list.data:")
        print(window_info_list.data)
        print("window_info.data:")
        print(window_info.data)
```

then console:

```
window_info_list.data:
[OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('add_time', '2020-03-24T03:43:13.091961'), ('user', 1)])]
window_info.data:
{}
```

why the window_info.data is {}?

Answer (score 0):

Must pass object as a first argument When serialize objects

```
window_info = WindowInfoSerializer(data=window_info)
```